Errors in all of xml files of the project "Cannot resolve class RelativeLayout", "Cannot resolve class TextView", "Cannot resolve class ImageView"
After invalidate caches in my project in android studio i broke all my activity files, and get the errors "Cannot resolve class TextView", "Cannot resolve class RelativeLayout"

Here is my build.gradle dependencies:
dependencies {

    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.activity)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.firebase.database)
    implementation(libs.firebase.auth)
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.livedata.ktx)
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
    implementation(libs.navigation.fragment)
    implementation(libs.navigation.ui)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1")
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.0.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation("com.github.rey5137:material:1.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:21.0.0")
    implementation("io.github.pilgr:paperdb:2.7.2")
    implementation("de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8")
    androidTestImplementation("org.testng:testng:6.9.6")
    implementation ("com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0") // или более новая версия
    implementation ("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+")
}

I tried to rebuild my project, invalidate caches again, update gradle dependencies, clean up the project. I tried to create a new project, but this problem is not there.

Include the contents of products_items_layout.xml - the first error suggests it is not well-formed.

I fixed it, but the problem remains

You still have not included the contents of the file.  It also needs to be text, not an image.
